# What's the difference between passing false and true to 'resolvingAgainstBaseURL' when initialize a NSURLComponents instance?

Tags: swift, url, nsurl, nsurlcomponents

I can't understand what's the difference between these two ways of calling:

```
NSURLComponents(URL: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true)
```

and

```
NSURLComponents(URL: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)
```

And I found the explanation of documentation was hard to understand...
Can someone please give me a simple example to show how this api works?
(I tried many different combinations of parameters , but what they yielded were same...)

Answer (score 159, accepted):

It makes only a difference if you create the URL components from an `NSURL` which 
was created relative to another `NSURL`:

```
let baseURL = NSURL(string: "http://server/foo/")!
let url = NSURL(string: "bar/file.html", relativeToURL: baseURL)!
print(url.absoluteString)
// "http://server/foo/bar/file.html"
```

With `resolvingAgainstBaseURL == false`, the URL components
represent only the relative part of the URL:

```
let comp1 = NSURLComponents(URL: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)!
print(comp1.string!)
// "bar/file.html"
```

With `resolvingAgainstBaseURL == true`, the URL components
represent the fully resolved URL:

```
let comp2 = NSURLComponents(URL: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true)!
print(comp2.string!)
// "http://server/foo/bar/file.html"
```

Comment: As precise an answer as it could possibly be

Comment: In general, passing YES is the correct behavior. You should only pass NO if you know you only want the relative string of a relative URL.